# giving user's ip address and display it in admin.py of a django project

Tags: python, django

how can i give ip address of users and display it in admin.py of django project?

I created view of it but i don't know how to display it in admin panel
this is my view function :

```
def get_ip_address(request):
    user_ip_address = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if user_ip_address:
        ip = user_ip_address.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip

def show_ip_address(request):
    user_ip = get_ip_address(request)
    return render(request, "output.html", {"user_ip":user_ip})
```